# Insert colon separator into timings ( i.e convert 1230a to 12:30a and 1430 to 14:30 )

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a requirement in my project whereby we have some input boxes and we are supposed to enter **timings**.

Timings can be entered in any format i.e **12:30a** or **1230** or **1430** or **14:30**.

The **problem with timings** entered in **1230 or 1430 format** is that **I cannot properly parse** them via **Data.parse('1230')**. I have to parse the timings to convert them into date objects so that i can perform more operations on them.

So for this requirement I have to enter a colon between these timings.I.E convert 1230 to 12:30 and 1430 to 14:30.

Timings I have to Support :

**12 Hour : 1230a,1230am,12:30a,12:30am**

**24 Hour : 1430,14:30**

Comment: Will they always be in the 24 hour clock (eg "0930"/"09:30" or will they be, by design or by accident, "9:30am")?

Comment: @DavidThomas...we are supporting both 12 hour (12:30a,12:30am,1230a,1230am) and 24 hour (1430,14:30)

Comment: `str.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$1:$2');` would insert a colon between any 4 digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you can use the regex `/\b(\d{1,2})(\d{2})/g` and replace it with `$1:$2`. You requested an explanation, which you're completely right to do.

**Javascript code**:

```
var str = '430a';

var newStr = str.replace(/\b(\d{1,2})(\d{2})/g, '$1:$2');

console.log(newStr); // "4:30a"
```

**Regex autopsy**:

- `/` - *The start of the regex - shows javascript that this is a regex - this needs to be repeated at the end*
- `\b` - *a word boundary, meaning a space, a period, a comma, a start of the string and the likes - it means we don't match `b182` as `b` is not a boundary*
- `(\d{1,2})` - *a capturing group matching a digit matched 1 to 2 times (both inclusive). Will match eg. "2" and "24"*
- `(\d{2})` - *a capturing group matching a digit **always** matched 2 times. Will match eg. "30"*
- `/` - *The end of the regex - it also is the separator for our modifier*
- `g` - *Our modifier - this means we'll replace **ANY** occurence and not simply the first one*

When we replace with `$1:$2` this means "the content of the first capturing group (`$1`), followed by a colon (`:`), followed by the content of the second capturing group (`$2`)".

**Transformation**:

```
1430             -> 14:30
1230a            -> 12:30a
1230am           -> 12:30am
430a             -> 4:30a
The year is 2015 -> The year is 20:15
123456           -> 12:3456
Blink182         -> Blink182 (untouched)
Blink 182        -> Blink 1:82
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/rA2hX3/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the whole thing but I am bit confused about the the two capturing group parts. i.e \d{1,2} matched 1 or 2 occurrence of a number and \d{2} matched two occurrences of a number. so i have 1230 \d{1,2} will match 1 and \d will match 23. how does this case works?

Comment: Nope, if you specify a range, it will always try to be as greedy as possible. `\d{1,2}` would therefore match 2 numbers, as there *are* two numbers available for it. It *knows* that the last 2 digits have to be present and in the second capturing group - this is **required** by our regex. The only question is whether the first group has 1 or 2 digits available. If 2 are available then it will match 2 because it's greedy.

Answer (score 3):

I made an answer that takes AM/PM into account as well:

```js
var tests = ['1230a','12:30am','1230pm','1230p','14','14:30', '130pm'];
//Regex to split text and numbers:
var regex = /(^\d{1,2}):?(\d{2})(\D*)$/;
console.log(tests);
tests.map(function(t) {
 var r = regex.exec(t);
 var date;
 if(r){//We have a parsable date
  //First group is hours:
  var hours = parseInt(r[1], 10);
  //Second group is minutes:
  var minutes = parseInt(r[2], 10);
  //If theres text we apply some rules:
  var spec = (r[3][0]||'').toLowerCase();
  if(spec == 'p' && hours !== 12){
   hours += 12;
  }
  else if(spec == 'a' && hours == 12){
   hours = 0;
  }
  //Here we construct the date:
  date = new Date();
  date.setHours(hours);
  date.setMinutes(minutes);
  date.setSeconds(0);
 }
 //If no match we return undefined:
 console.log(t + ': ', date);
 return date;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following regex:

```
var re = /^(\d{1,2})(\d{2})/; 
var str = '1430';
var subst = '$1:$2'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hT0qL5/4).

Comment: Updated. It is good for checking independent values, which is exactly the case.